# Most efficient way to check if an object is a value type

Tags: c#, .net, performance, value-type

**WARNING: THIS CODE SUCKS, SEE ANTHONY'S COMMENTS**

Which is faster?

1.

```
  public bool IsValueType<T>(T obj){
       return obj is ValueType;
  }
```

2.

```
  public bool IsValueType<T>(T obj){
       return obj == null ? false : obj.GetType().IsValueType;
  }
```

3.

```
  public bool IsValueType<T>(T obj){
       return default(T) != null;
  }
```

4.Something else

Comment: Does the performance really matter because it is really micro-optimatisation

Comment: Methods 2 and 3 as written are invalid. `obj == null ||` will return true for reference types. `default(T) != null` will return false for the `Nullable<T>` structs.

Comment: Your edit on method 2 is still going to be invalid. `obj != null ||` will return true for non-null reference-type objects.

Comment: @PoweRoy, if I do it a whole bunch I'm sure it won't hurt to do it the right way

Comment: Since I'm being hypercritical, er, I mean helpful, method 1 doesn't like nulled `Nullable<T>` objects. `int? bar = null;` Pass that through the function, you get false. (Didn't expect that, to be honest.)

Comment: Method 2 latest edit. `return obj == null ? false : ...` still presents a problem for `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @Anthony, how about now?

Comment: @smartcaveman, yes, admitting defeat. I think you're on the right track by following Marc's answer, the three methods you've presented (and their various iterations) all have their various problems.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You aren't really testing an object - you want to test the *type*. To call those, the caller must know the type, but... meh. Given a signature `<T>(T obj)` the only sane answer is:

```
public bool IsValueType<T>() {
    return typeof(T).IsValueType;
}
```

or if we want to use an example object for type inference purposes:

```
public bool IsValueType<T>(T obj) {
    return typeof(T).IsValueType;
}
```

this doesn't need boxing (`GetType()` is boxing), and doesn't have problems with `Nullable<T>`. A more interesting case is when you are passing `object`...

```
 public bool IsValueType(object obj);
```

here, we already have massive problems with `null`, since that could be an empty `Nullable<T>` (a struct) or a class. But A reasonable attempt would be:

```
public bool IsValueType(object obj) {
    return obj != null && obj.GetType().IsValueType;
}
```

but note that it is incorrect (and unfixable) for empty `Nullable<T>`s. Here it becomes pointless to worry about boxing as we are already boxed.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass the `IsValueType` property? I'm using the .NET DNX, which doesn't support this property.

Comment: `typeof(ValueType).IsAssignableFrom(t)` doesn't work either.

Comment: @Shimmy -- in the OP's code -- `if (default(T) != null)` should work.

Comment: In DNX / .NET Core you can do that like this `typeof(your_type).GetTypeInfo().IsValueType`.

Answer (score 8):

My first answer would be to write a simple test and find out for yourself.

My second answer (without any testing on my part, of course) would be **option 1**. It is the simplest check. The second method involves two separate checks while the third involves creating a default instance of a type.

You should also consider readability. The framework already gives you the ability to have the following in your code:

```
if(someObj is ValueType)
{
    // Do some work
}
```

Why even bother creating a method that would simply turn the above statement into (assuming you made your method static and allowed the compiler to infer the generic type):

```
if(IsValueType(someObj))
{
    // Do some work
}
```

Comment: thanks - and I wasn't advocating creating a method for testing it.  I just wrote it that way for clarity about what I was asking

Comment: the `(someObj is ValueType)` appears to be problematic for nulled `Nullable<T>`. I'm no IL guru, but I believe there is boxing involved and that does not play well with this scenario.

Comment: How you know `is` is the simplest check? You can test for example if an object implements an interface with it, which is not so "simple". Don't know how compiler deals with it but check out how [IsAssignableFrom](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,ba0cffea035fe210) and [ImplementInterface](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,95fa6055bd315eed) (called by it) are implemented. Do you know something more, or you just think `is` is faster because it looks simpler?

Answer (score 3):

Defining a struct actually defines two types: a value type, and a class type which derives from `System.ValueType`.  If a request is made to create a variable, parameter, field, or array (collectively, 'storage location') of a type which derives from System.ValueType, the system will instead create a storage location which will store the object's fields rather than storing a reference to an object in which those fields appear.  On the other hand, if a request is made to create an instance of a type deriving from System.ValueType, the system will create an object instance of a class which derives from System.ValueType.

This may be demonstrated by creating a struct which implements IValue:

```
interface IValue {int value {get; set;}};
struct ValueStruct : IValue
{
  public int value {get; set;}};
}
```

with generic test routine and code to wrap it:

```
static void Test<T>(T it) where T:IValue
{
  T duplicate = it;
  it.value += 1;
  duplicate.value += 10;
  Console.WriteLine(it.value.ToString());
}
static void Test()
{
  ValueStruct v1 = new ValueStruct();
  v1.value = 9;
  IValue v2 = v1;
  Test<ValueStruct>(v1); 
  Test<ValueStruct>(v1); 
  Test<IValue>(v1); 
  Test<IValue>(v1); 
  Test<IValue>(v2);
  Test<IValue>(v2);
}
```

Note that in every case, calling GetType on the parameter passed to Test would yield ValueStruct, which will report itself as a value type.  Nonetheless, the passed-in item will only be a "real" value type on the first two calls.  On the third and fourth calls, it will really be a class type, as demonstrated by the fact that a change to `duplicate` will affect `it`.  And on the fifth and sixth calls, the change will be propagated back to v2, so the second call will "see" it.

Comment: One would usually describe this as boxing... On third and forth call you are boxing on the method call itself: when T is an interface, `it` is a boxed value (sometimes this boxing can be optimized away though), and duplicate is simply a reference to that box. On the fifth and sixth call you are passing in objects which are already boxed, because `IValue v2 = v1;` created a box. Since you are passing in the same box twice instead of creating two separate boxes, the changes made to the box on the first call are visible on the second call.

Comment: @AnorZaken: The term "boxing" is indeed used to describe the process.  I don't have the documentation for the .NET internals handy, but it does indeed describe the process in terms of having two separate types, and I think recognizing that a boxed struct as being an `Object` while an unboxed struct isn't is clearer than the abstraction model used in C#.  VB.NET adds some of its own silly logic into the mix.  If an interface-type reference identifies a boxed value type instance, converting the reference to type `Object` will re-box the instance for some reason I don't quite fathom.

Answer (score 3):

```
static class Metadata<T>
{
    static public readonly Type Type = typeof(T);
    static public readonly bool IsValueType = Metadata<T>.Type.IsValueType;
}

//fast test if T is ValueType
if(Metadata<T>.IsValueType) //only read static readonly field!
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: The limitation of this is that it is based on `typeof(T)` rather than testing an incoming instance. Usually a programmer knows whether a specific `type` is value or not, the common need is to know whether an `instance` is value or not. **Consider a method parameter `object obj`. This answer will evaluate that based on `T=object`, the declared parameter type, not a specific instance's runtime type, so will return `false`, no matter what `obj` is.** But `obj` might be a **boxed** integer or other value type.

Answer (score 0):

There are two rules:

1-All Classes are **reference** types such as Object and String, so it's supported by .NET Framework **classes**.

2-All structures are **value** types such as bool and char, even though it contain reference member, so it's supported by .NET Framework **structures**.

Simply right click on any type and **Go To Definition** if it's a Class so that means it a reference type else if it's a Struct so that means it's a value type :)

Comment: ++ for the background info, but what do you mean by "even though it contain reference member"? Also, I assume that the GUI instructions refer to Visual Studio, correct?

Comment: Right it's refer to Visual studio, and I mean that you can have struct contains an object reference.... and You could find those 2 sentences on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

"class is a reference type. For this reason, reference types such as Object and String are supported by .NET Framework classes. Note that every array is a reference type, even if its members are value types."

"structure is a value type, even if it contains reference type members. For this reason, value types such as Char and Integer are implemented by .NET Framework structures."

Comment: Interesting, but the question is about code, not about finding out in an IDE.

Comment: The question was about a generic type T, remember? "Go To Definition" won't help with T.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
obj.GetType().IsValueType
```

This uses reflection but clear way instead of care of boxing unboxing.

Comment: That reply does not answer the question.