# Check to see if a given object (reference or value type) is equal to its default

Tags: c#, default-value, generics

I'm trying to find a way to check and see if the value of a given object is equal to its default value. I've looked around and come up with this:

```
    public static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(T argument)
    {
        if (argument is ValueType || argument != null)
        {
            return object.Equals(argument, default(T));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that I want to call it like this:

```
            object o = 0;
            bool b = Utility.Utility.IsNullOrDefault(o);
```

Yes o is an object, but I want to make it figure out the base type and check the default value of that. The base type, in this case, is an integer and I want to know in this case if the value is equal to default(int), not default(object).

I'm starting to think this might not be possible.

Comment: Why not call it like var o = 0; ?

Comment: I can't because I'm getting the value from the `GetValue` method in `PropertyInfo` which only returns an `object`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to check if an object is a value type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748661/most-efficient-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-value-type)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In your example, your integer is boxed and therefore your `T` is going to be `object`, and the default of object is null, so that's not valuable to you. If the object is a value type, you could get an instance of it (which would be the default) to use as a comparison. Something like:

```
if (argument is ValueType)
{
   object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(argument.GetType());
   return obj.Equals(argument);
}
```

You'd want to deal with other possibilities before resorting to this. [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553183/check-to-see-if-a-given-object-reference-or-value-type-is-equal-to-its-default/6553303#6553303) brings up some good points to consider, but for a full version of your method, you might have

```
public static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(T argument)
{
    // deal with normal scenarios
    if (argument == null) return true;
    if (object.Equals(argument, default(T))) return true;

    // deal with non-null nullables
    Type methodType = typeof(T);
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(methodType) != null) return false;

    // deal with boxed value types
    Type argumentType = argument.GetType();
    if (argumentType.IsValueType && argumentType != methodType) 
    {
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(argument.GetType());
        return obj.Equals(argument);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Another way you could implement this is to code it as an extension:
`public static bool IsNullOrDeafult<T>(this T argument)`

Comment: As Marc Gravell points out, but I didn't get at first: when a nullable value is boxed it is either a null or a value,type. E.g. 

 object o = (int?) 0;
 Debug.Assert(o.GetType() == typeof(int));  // Not int?

So, I think it is misleading to offer a generic method where:
 IsNullOrDefault((int?) 0) -- returns false, but
 
 IsNullOrDefault((object) (int?) 0) -- returns true

(The casts are not real use cases, but boxing does occur in useful scenarios.)

IMO a better solution is to pass in the explicit run-time type.

Answer (score 10):

if `o` is null, in  a non-generic (`object`) method, you will have no access to the original type - and you can't do much about that.

Hence, the only time it matters is non-nullable value-types, so:

```
Type type = value.GetType();
if(!type.IsValueType) return false; // can't be, as would be null
if(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null) return false; // ditto, Nullable<T>
object defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // must exist for structs
return value.Equals(defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 5):

Converted [Anthony Pegram's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6553276/1889720) into an extension method:

```
using System;

//Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6553276/1889720
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrDefault<TObject>(this TObject argument)
    {
        // deal with normal scenarios
        if (argument == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (object.Equals(argument, default(TObject)))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // deal with non-null nullables
        Type methodType = typeof(TObject);
        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(methodType) != null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // deal with boxed value types
        Type argumentType = argument.GetType();
        if (argumentType.IsValueType && argumentType != methodType)
        {
            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(argument.GetType());
            return obj.Equals(argument);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage syntax:

```
myVariable.IsNullOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Marc Gravell's answer, by getting the run-time type as an argument:

```
// Handles boxed value types
public static bool IsNullOrDefault([CanBeNull] this object @object,
    [NotNull] Type runtimeType)
{
    if (@object == null) return true;

    if (runtimeType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("runtimeType");

    // Handle non-null reference types.
    if (!runtimeType.IsValueType) return false;

    // Nullable, but not null
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(runtimeType) != null) return false;

    // Use CreateInstance as the most reliable way to get default value for a value type
    object defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(runtimeType);

    return defaultValue.Equals(@object);
}
```

For those of you that will challenge my use case, I want to list the values of properties on an arbitrary object, omitting properties which set to their defaults (for a more concise display).

Because propertyInfo.GetValue(targetObject, null) returns an object, and value types are boxed, I cannot use a generic method. By passing propertyInfo.PropertyType as the second parameter to this method I can avoid the problem a generic method has with boxed value types.

Comment: Well expressed. I have a very similar use case. Unfortunately the way C# has evolved using object as a base type, and then generic types and then nullable types, a simple check like `value == default(type)` has to be expressed in such elaborate detail. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following will sort it out.

```
    public static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(T argument)
{
    if (argument is ValueType || argument != null)
    {
        return object.Equals(argument, GetDefault(argument.GetType()));
    }
    return true;
}


public static object GetDefault(Type type)
{
    if(type.IsValueType)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an extension method

```
 public static class DateExtension
{
    public static bool IsNullOrDefault(this DateTime? value)
    {
        return default(DateTime) == value || default(DateTime?) == value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with linq expressions. First call for type will be relatively slow, but then it should work just as quick as usual code.

```
public static class DefaultHelper
{
    private delegate bool IsDefaultValueDelegate(object value);

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IsDefaultValueDelegate> Delegates
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IsDefaultValueDelegate>();

    public static bool IsDefaultValue(this object value)
    {
        var type = value.GetType();
        var isDefaultDelegate = Delegates.GetOrAdd(type, CreateDelegate);
        return isDefaultDelegate(value);
    }

    private static IsDefaultValueDelegate CreateDelegate(Type type)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        var expression = Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Convert(parameter, type),
            Expression.Default(type));
        return Expression.Lambda<IsDefaultValueDelegate>(expression, parameter).Compile();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply store default value in dictionary and compare it instead of creating expression.