# Find item in IList with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have an IList:

```
IList list = CallMyMethodToGetIList();
```

that I don't know the type I can get it

```
Type entityType = list[0].GetType();`
```

I would like to search this list with LINQ something like:

```
var itemFind = list.SingleOrDefault(MyCondition....);
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does your condition look like for if you don't know the type?

Comment: start with var itemFind = list.Where( i => myCondition(i))....

Comment: Since you're using the non generic `IList`, you need to add `.OfType<T>` or `.Cast<T>` before using othe LINQ methods. If your items don't belong to the same type you can simply use `object` as `T` i.e. `.OfType<object>()`

Comment: If you know that the type derives from an interface, cast to the interface and use an interface method. If you know the type implements a specific method, try using dynamic.

Comment: I'm very excited! Please show us condition which works with any type!

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It's not hard to write such a condition, it's simply coming up with a useful one that may or may not be easy.  For example, any type will have a `ToString`, you can determine if `obj.ToString()` is null.

Comment: What is the signature of the condition?

Comment: @Servy yep, I mentioned some with business value :) sure each object has at least four methods

Comment: You are aware that `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if more than one item is found, yes? "Single" in this case does not mean "give me only one". If you intended to "give me only one," then use `FirstOrDefault` with the answers provided.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Simple:

```
IList list = MyIListMethod();

var item = list
    .Cast<object>()
    .SingleOrDefault(i => i is MyType);
```

or:

```
IList list = MyIListMethod();

var item = list
    .Cast<object>()
    .SingleOrDefault(i => i != null);
```

hope this help!

Comment: `OfType<MyType>()` will do this for you.

Comment: basically the are `foreach(item) yield return (T)item` and `foreach(item) if (item is T) yield return item as T` respectively.

Comment: What if the type is a non-nullable value type?

Comment: The filters in `.SingleOrDefault(xxx)` are ONLY for example.
I mean the `.Cast<object>()` method.

...but your question is interesting!
Give me some mins...

Comment: The simplest way, in a generic method, like this:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553183/check-to-see-if-a-given-object-reference-or-value-type-is-equal-to-its-default)

Answer (score 8):

```
IList list = ...

// if all items are of given type
IEnumerable<YourType> seq = list.Cast<YourType>().Where(condition);

// if only some of them    
IEnumerable<YourType> seq = list.OfType<YourType>().Where(condition);
```

Comment: I was under the impression the type was not known at compile time since he used `list[0].GetType()` to get the type. I agree with your comment at my answer that `dynamic` is not very efficient, but it supports for Linq.