# True condition evaluates to false

Tags: c#, reflection

I am writing a basic model validator that uses reflection with a custom "Required" attribute. When a model is passed into the validator method, all properties are checked for this required attribute. Complex types are recursively validated as well. When a property is found with this attribute, it will either compare the value to null if it is a nullable type, else it will compare to default.

I'm having issues when comparing non-nullable type to default. The following condition is evaluating to false for type int, but it should be true:

```
if (prop.GetValue(testObject) == default)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{VALIDATION_FAILED_MESSAGE}: {baseObjectName}{testObject.GetType().Name}.{prop.Name} is null.");
    isNullorDefault = true;
}
```

I see in the debugger that the value being compared is without a doubt the default value ->
default(int) == 0, but it is evaluating to false. Why?

[image]

Comment: (Nearly) Everything in Reflection is based on `System.Object`. Your use of `default` in that context is very likely being interpreted as `default(object)`, i.e., `null`

Answer (score 7):

Well, here are a few facts:

- `GetValue` returns an `object`, which is a reference type
- `==` on objects does a reference comparison (so true if both are the *same* object).
- Value types are always boxed to a new object when cast to `object`.
- `default` without a type is simply inferred based on context, and here it's `object`, so `null`.

Therefore, this comparison can *never* evaluate to true: a boxed value type is never `null`, and even if you did `GetValue(x) == (object)0`, it would still be false because that `0` would get boxed to a different object, and as such, different references compare differently.

So that's your answer as for *why* this is happening. For a solution to the actual thing you're trying to do, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553183).