# c# Merging lists with double properties

Tags: c#, list, merge, union

I have searched for this code online to merge several lists and return one.  The code works if all properties are string but I get an error if some of the properties are double.  This error is "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'double'".  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Project> lst1; List<Project> lst2; List<Project> lst3;
            lst1 = new List<Project> 
            {
                new Project { ProjectId = 1, ProjectName = "P1" },
                new Project { ProjectId = 2, ProjectName = "P2" },
                new Project { ProjectId = 3, ProjectName = "P3" }
            };
                    lst2 = new List<Project>
            {
                new Project { ProjectId = 1, CustomerNum = 1},
                new Project { ProjectId = 2, CustomerNum = 2},
                new Project { ProjectId = 3, CustomerNum = 3}
            };
                    lst3 = new List<Project>
            {
                new Project { ProjectId = 1, Address = 10},
                new Project { ProjectId = 2, Address = 20},
                new Project { ProjectId = 3, Address = 30}
            };

                    List<Project> lst = lst1.Union(lst2).Union(lst3).ToLookup(x => x.ProjectId).Select(x => new Project()
                    {
                        ProjectId = x.Key,
                        ProjectName = x.Select(y => y.ProjectName).Aggregate((z1, z2) => z1 ?? z2),
                        CustomerNum = x.Select(y => y.CustomerNum).Aggregate((z1, z2) => z1 ?? z2),
                        Address = x.Select(y => y.Address).Aggregate((z1, z2) => z1 ?? z2)
                    }).ToList();


            foreach (var item in lst)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", item.ProjectId, item.ProjectName, item.CustomerNum, item.Address);

            }     
        }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public double CustomerNum { get; set; }
        public double Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Null-coalescing do not work against a non-nullable type (`double`) on the left-hand side

From [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for **nullable value types or reference types**

So, you could use a `double?` (`Nullable<double>`) and this would work. But, as written the left-hand side would always have a value, thus your problem. [Alternatively, you could check if the type is a value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748661/most-efficient-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-value-type)?

Comment: Random downvoter, could you possibly explain the downvote if still around?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to do the same thing that you're doing with your other types, you can do the following

```
CustomerNum = x.Select(y => y.CustomerNum).Aggregate((z1, z2) => z1)
```

Comment: Since z1 is a double, it will never be null.  Not sure if you can even compare it to null.

Comment: This is just a longer version of the `??` operator, it doesn't change anything functionally. It also doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @BillGregg I was under the impression that `z1` and `z2` could be a number of types, some that are nullable.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel there is a difference.  a ternary operator doesn't throw an error.  the `??` operator does.

Comment: @SamIam: fair enough, there is a difference in functionality. But the situation can't occur since a `double` can't be `null` in the first place.

Comment: The code runs but the last two double fields are zero.  I also get this message: "The results of the expression is always false since a value of type double is never equal to null type double"

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I wrote my answer from a place where I had assumed that he'd use the same code with different types too.  At any rate, I've changed it so that is no longer the case

Comment: @user3072518 well, it's functionally equivalent to what your code would have done had it compiled.  I've edited the answer to be more specific to `doubles` maybe you can try that out.  It's still functionally equivalent to what your code would have done had it compiled.

Comment: @SamIam I tried it with the revised code and returns zero for the last two fields with no warning

Answer (score 0):

?? is used to say "If the left side is null, then use the value on the right side".  Since Double is a value type, it can never be null.  So you will always just get the left side of the property.  The compiler is telling you your code is suspicious.

Use a Double? if you want to keep the exact same code.

Comment: No, I wasn't saying replace the ??.  Your issue is the types.  double ?? double is not valid, because double is not nullable.  But double? ?? double? is valid, because double? is a nullable double.  It is a different type.

Comment: thank you for your input.  How do you suggest changing the code?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple (long) solution that works. Here is the code for the merged list

```
        List<Project> lst = new List<Project>();

        for (int i = 0; i < lst1.Count; i++)
        {
            double cusnum = 0;
            var lst2q = (from s in lst2
                            where s.ProjectId == lst1[i].ProjectId
                            select s).ToArray();

            if (lst2q.Length > 0)
            {
                cusnum = lst2q[0].CustomerNum;
            }


            var lst3q = (from s in lst3
                         where s.ProjectId == lst1[i].ProjectId
                         select s).ToArray();

            double cusadd = 0;
            if (lst3q.Length > 0)
            {
                cusadd = lst3q[0].Address;
            }

            lst.Add(new Project
                {
                    ProjectId = lst1[i].ProjectId,
                    ProjectName = lst1[i].ProjectName,
                    CustomerNum = cusnum,
                    Address = cusadd,
                });
        }
```